# Cassandra - valid_from / valid_to query

Tags: cassandra, cql3

I am trying to figure out what would be the best way to implement a valid from/to data filtering in Cassandra.

I need to have a table with records that are only valid in certain time window - always defined. Each of such records would not be valid for more than lets say: 3 months.

I would like to have a structure like this (more less ofc):

userId bigint,
validFrom timestamp ( or maybe split into columns like: from_year, from_month etc. if that helps )
validTo timestamp ( or as above )
someCollection set

All queries would be performed by userId, validFrom, validTo.

I know the limits of querying in Cassandra (both PK and clustering keys) but maybe I am missing some trick or clever usage of what is available in CQL.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You could just select by validFrom but TTL the data by the validTo to make sure the number of records you need to filter in your app doesn't get too large. However, depending on how many records you have per user this may result in a lot of tombstones.

Comment: This sounds like a quite good idea. TTL would have to be calculated basing on insert time and valid to. Would have to check if we can make it precise enough (since TTL is in seconds).

Comment: There would not be so many tombstones. Maybe a few million / month. And if I use DateTiered Compaction Strategy in 2.1.x it would not be a big issue.

Comment: I was also thinking about filtering by valid_to (search_date <= valid_to). Of course part of the filtering would have to be done in memory, but it should not be too many of such rows.